# ElasticSearch aggregate use doc_count for average

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, jodatime

I'm just diving into the new aggregate functions in ElasticSearch 1.0. I'm trying to fetch some statistical data on a bunch of documents (loglines).

Every document counts as a hit, and I want to fetch the average number of hits per hour, over a given period. Every document has a datetime reference, and every document counts as a 'hit'.

The first bit is easy (querying and filtering), and I get all the document I want to match fir the given period. But I can't figure out how to get an average of the document count.

I can get a list of all the document per day, per hour, and make some statistical calculations on the client side, but I would love to have it all done in ElasticSearch. My guess is it can be done via the doc_count, but I can't find any information on it.

I can get a list of all the documents within an hour, in the given timeframe. If I try this with an aggregate over the hour:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "articles_over_time" : {
        "histogram" : {
            "script" : "doc['created_at'].date.hourOfDay",
            "interval" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

I get a list of documents per hour over the given period, but they are sum()'ed together, I would love to get an average (or even better: the actual 'stats' aggregate). Not on a document field, but on the doc_count itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, I ended up doing the aggregates on the client side code, I haven't found any solution to do this in ES so far.

Comment: Thanks, I finally did it on client side too. I'm sure it's possible, but I'm missing something...

Comment: Yeah, I figured there must be some way to get to the count via the script tag perhaps, but couldn't find any references anywhere :( I Love ES so far though ;)

Comment: I think for that you have to manipulate the response, es don't provide this type of feature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done from the server side itself but using a work around.
hits.total should give total number of document. You can do a min and max stats on the timestamp field and from that compute the total number of hours. 
Now

```
(hits.total)/(Total Number of hours)
```

should give you what you are looking for.

There is another approach. You can use the metric aggregation script feature to do the above using a script.
LINK - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html

But then , the real feature you are looking is called metric reducer.
It is not available as of now , but then there is an issue on it - https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8110